# How to build a binary-array from hex strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, bit-manipulation

I'm new to the concept of working with data on the binary level and am hoping someone can give me a hand here...

I'd like to build a binary buffer out of a series of hex numbers that are represented as strings.

For example,

suppose I have "**xFCx40xFF**" and I want to turn this into an array that looks like: **111111000100000011111111**.

What's the best way to do this?

My best attempt seems to not be working:

```
var raw = "xFCx40xFF"
var end = raw.length-2;
var i = 1;
var j = 0;
var myArray = new Uint8Array(raw.len);
while (i < end) {
    var s = raw.substr(i,2);
    var num = parseInt(s,16);
    i += 3;
    myArray[j] = num;
    j += 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each 3 characters in string will represent 1 number in Uint8Array. Each number in Uint8Array will represent 8 bits. Your code was creating Uint8Array larger than needed and then placing values are wrong locations.

I have simplified the code to use a singe index i which represents the location in the Uint8Array. Corresponding location in string can be easily computed from i.

```
var raw = "xFCx40xFF"
var myArray = new Uint8Array(raw.length / 3);
for (var i = 0; i < raw.length / 3; i++) {
    var str = raw.substr(3 * i + 1, 2);
    var num = parseInt(str, 16);
    myArray[i] = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'x' character of your hex string and call `parseInt()` with the radix `16` and `toString()` with the radix `2` to get the binary string.

```js
var raw = "xFCx40xFF";
var bin = parseInt(raw.split('x').join(''), 16).toString(2);
document.body.textContent = bin;
```

and if you need an array, just add .split('') at the end.

```
parseInt(raw.split('x').join(''), 16).toString(2).split('');
```

or iterate through each character.

Comment: I like the cleverness in this solution, but it won't work for really long hex strings